# PHP eMailing script

Tags: php, html, email, user-accounts

So I wrote a php script that sends a user a temporary password for when the forget their password so they can login and change it. The script works fine, and the email gets sent with all the correct information. The thing i want to change is who it is getting sent by. I want to use google email app for websites to send those emails, rather the emails are getting sent by my webserver. Here's what the sending part of my script looks like:

```
$email_to = $_POST["email"];
$email_from = "Admin@domain.com";
$email_subject = "Account Information Recovery";
$email_message = "Here is your temporary password:\n\n";

$email_message .= "Password: ".$password."\n";
$email_message .= "\nPlease log into your account and immediately change your password.";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

However when I receive the email, it comes from `Admin@webserver`. How do I use google's email app to send these emails?

Comment: This is because the php 'mail' function sends the 'MAIL FROM' as the server's default mail address, setting the header from address is not enough.

Comment: I know that `google-app-engine` is the first thing that comes up when you type in `google` but really, please try and tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: PHP's `mail()` function sucks. I recommend avoiding it. Use a decent class like [phpMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) instead -- you'll save yourself a lot of effort.

Comment: PHPMailer is good, also you might want to see SwiftMailer, which is even more powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).  It's got a very nice and well-documented API, and supports all different kinds of transports.

From the docs:

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

// Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.example.org', 25)
  ->setUsername('your username')
  ->setPassword('your password')
  ;

/*
You could alternatively use a different transport such as Sendmail or Mail:

// Sendmail
$transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');

// Mail
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
*/

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably best to use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/):

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; //1 for debugging, spits info out  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; //needed for GMail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->Username = 'google_username';  
$mail->Password = 'google_password';           
$mail->SetFrom($email_from, 'Your Website Name');
$mail->Subject = $email_subject;
$mail->Body = $email_message;
$mail->AddAddress($email_to);
$mail->Send();
```

Note: This example uses SMTP directly to send the email, which will correct the issue, but if the host has fsockopen disabled it will not work.

Comment: so i included `phpmailer.inc.php` and had to do `$mail = new phpmailer();`. Am I using the right version? Also where do I go to see the output for debugging and how do I check for fsockopen? Thanks

Comment: Download the latest version from here: http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/